# Convert to UNICODE in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unicode, encode

```
public  string DecodeFromUtf8(string utf8String)
{
    // copy the string as UTF-8 bytes.
    byte[] utf8Bytes = new byte[utf8String.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < utf8String.Length; ++i)
    {
        //Debug.Assert( 0 <= utf8String[i] && utf8String[i] <= 255, 
        //"the char must be in byte's range");
        utf8Bytes[i] = (byte)utf8String[i];
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes, 0, utf8Bytes.Length);
}
```

this code doesn't work for me 
do you have any good ideas?

i need the unicode array for russian fonts like this

```
 public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> Unicodes = Array.AsReadOnly(new char[] 
    {
        '\u0000', '\u0001', '\u0002', '\u0003', '\u0004', '\u0005', '\u0006', '\u0007', 
        '\u0008', '\u0009', '\u000A', '\u000B', '\u000C', '\u000D', '\u000E', '\u000F', 
        '\u0010', '\u0011', '\u0012', '\u0013', '\u0014', '\u0015', '\u0016', '\u0017', 
        '\u0018', '\u0019', '\u001A', '\u001B', '\u001C', '\u001D', '\u001E', '\u001F', 
        '\u0020', '\u0021', '\u0022', '\u0023', '\u0024', '\u0025', '\u0026', '\u0027', 
        '\u0028', '\u0029', '\u002A', '\u002B', '\u002C', '\u002D', '\u002E', '\u002F', 
        '\u0030', '\u0031', '\u0032', '\u0033', '\u0034', '\u0035', '\u0036', '\u0037', 
        '\u0038', '\u0039', '\u003A', '\u003B', '\u003C', '\u003D', '\u003E', '\u003F', 
        '\u0040', '\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u0044', '\u0045', '\u0046', '\u0047', 
        '\u0048', '\u0049', '\u004A', '\u004B', '\u004C', '\u004D', '\u004E', '\u004F', 
        '\u0050', '\u0051', '\u0052', '\u0053', '\u0054', '\u0055', '\u0056', '\u0057', 
        '\u0058', '\u0059', '\u005A', '\u005B', '\u005C', '\u005D', '\u005E', '\u005F', 
        '\u0060', '\u0061', '\u0062', '\u0063', '\u0064', '\u0065', '\u0066', '\u0067', 
        '\u0068', '\u0069', '\u006A', '\u006B', '\u006C', '\u006D', '\u006E', '\u006F', 
        '\u0070', '\u0071', '\u0072', '\u0073', '\u0074', '\u0075', '\u0076', '\u0077', 
        '\u0078', '\u0079', '\u007A', '\u007B', '\u007C', '\u007D', '\u007E', '\u007F', 
        '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', 
        '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', 
        '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', 
        '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', '\uFFFD', 
        '\u00A0', '\u058E', '\u0587', '\u0589', '\u0029', '\u0028', '\u00BB', '\u00AB', 
        '\u2015', '\u00B7', '\u055D', '\u002C', '\u2010', '\u058A', '\u2026', '\u055C', 
        '\u055B', '\u055E', '\u0531', '\u0561', '\u0532', '\u0562', '\u0533', '\u0563', 
        '\u0534', '\u0564', '\u0535', '\u0565', '\u0536', '\u0566', '\u0537', '\u0567', 
        '\u0538', '\u0568', '\u0539', '\u0569', '\u053A', '\u056A', '\u053B', '\u056B', 
        '\u053C', '\u056C', '\u053D', '\u056D', '\u053E', '\u056E', '\u053F', '\u056F', 
        '\u0540', '\u0570', '\u0541', '\u0571', '\u0542', '\u0572', '\u0543', '\u0573', 
        '\u0544', '\u0574', '\u0545', '\u0575', '\u0546', '\u0576', '\u0547', '\u0577', 
        '\u0548', '\u0578', '\u0549', '\u0579', '\u054A', '\u057A', '\u054B', '\u057B', 
        '\u054C', '\u057C', '\u054D', '\u057D', '\u054E', '\u057E', '\u054F', '\u057F', 
        '\u0550', '\u0580', '\u0551', '\u0581', '\u0552', '\u0582', '\u0553', '\u0583', 
        '\u0554', '\u0584', '\u0555', '\u0585', '\u0556', '\u0586', '\u055A', '\uFFFD' });
```

Comment: How should it work? What is the input?

Comment: text in Russian or Armenian
for example i have this           ÎÛáõñ»ÕÛ³Ý ºÉ»Ý³ Ú.
and i need it in UNICODE

Comment: What should your code do? Can you explain what you tried to make?

Comment: That's not Russian or Armenia text - it's just a mess. It's not clear what you mean by "in Unicode" either... all strings in .NET are Unicode. Please give us more context. I strongly suspect you need to change the code that obtains a string in the first place, probably to specify a different encoding.

Comment: i have this texts in acces db ,
ÎÛáõñ»ÕÛ³Ý ºÉ»Ý³ Ú.
I want to import it to SQL ,
I need to convert it to UNICODE to use in SQL and C#

Comment: Can you give an example that works with online utf-8 decoders like [this](http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder)?

Comment: I cant use online decoders because i have big datas and its immpossible to convert online

Comment: I only want a valid example. I want to check if your data is really utf-8. It looks like your data is not utf-8....

Comment: i want to convert this "Ø³ñïÇñáëÛ³Ý ²ÉÇÝ³ Ø." to this  "Մարտիրոսյան Ալինա Մ."

Comment: It isn't UTF8, it is ArmSCII-8. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArmSCII . No similar encoding is present in .NET, you'll have to build it.

Comment: That Մ looks like it is [Unicode Character 'ARMENIAN CAPITAL LETTER MEN' (U+0544)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0544/index.htm) which is 0xD5 0x84 in utf-8. Your first utf-8 input is Ø [Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH STROKE' (U+00F8)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00F8/index.htm). That does not map to D5

Comment: They aren't called "fonts". They are called "codepages" or "encodings". Fonts are the files that describe the "shape" (how to draw) a character set. "russian" is too much generic. If you have a piece of text that you can't decode correctly, you can ask for help. You put the "original" text and what should be the "decoded" text and then someone can often helo you, like when you wrote *i want to convert this "Ø³ñïÇñáëÛ³Ý ²ÉÇÝ³ Ø." to this "Մարտիրոսյան Ալինա Մ."*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string seems to be [ArmSCII-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArmSCII#ArmSCII-8).

Adapted from an old encoder/decoder I had written for VISCII:

```
namespace Utilities
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
    using System.Text;

    /// <summary>
    /// ArmSCII8 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArmSCII#ArmSCII-8)
    /// encoding for C#.
    /// Fast table-based implementation not based on MappedEncoding.
    /// Fully thread safe/reentrant (because ArmSCII8Encoder is fully thread
    /// safe/reentrant and ArmSCII8Decoder is always used with flush = true).
    /// </summary>
    public class ArmSCII8EncodingSimple : Encoding
    {
        // Taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ArmSCII#ArmSCII-8 .
        // Includes parts of the ISO-8859-1 in the ranges 00–1F and 7F–9F.
        // Doesn't define anything for FF.
        public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<char> Unicodes = Array.AsReadOnly(new char[] 
        {
            '\u0000', '\u0001', '\u0002', '\u0003', '\u0004', '\u0005', '\u0006', '\u0007', 
            '\u0008', '\u0009', '\u000A', '\u000B', '\u000C', '\u000D', '\u000E', '\u000F', 
            '\u0010', '\u0011', '\u0012', '\u0013', '\u0014', '\u0015', '\u0016', '\u0017', 
            '\u0018', '\u0019', '\u001A', '\u001B', '\u001C', '\u001D', '\u001E', '\u001F', 
            '\u0020', '\u0021', '\u0022', '\u0023', '\u0024', '\u0025', '\u0026', '\u0027', 
            '\u0028', '\u0029', '\u002A', '\u002B', '\u002C', '\u002D', '\u002E', '\u002F', 
            '\u0030', '\u0031', '\u0032', '\u0033', '\u0034', '\u0035', '\u0036', '\u0037', 
            '\u0038', '\u0039', '\u003A', '\u003B', '\u003C', '\u003D', '\u003E', '\u003F', 
            '\u0040', '\u0041', '\u0042', '\u0043', '\u0044', '\u0045', '\u0046', '\u0047', 
            '\u0048', '\u0049', '\u004A', '\u004B', '\u004C', '\u004D', '\u004E', '\u004F', 
            '\u0050', '\u0051', '\u0052', '\u0053', '\u0054', '\u0055', '\u0056', '\u0057', 
            '\u0058', '\u0059', '\u005A', '\u005B', '\u005C', '\u005D', '\u005E', '\u005F', 
            '\u0060', '\u0061', '\u0062', '\u0063', '\u0064', '\u0065', '\u0066', '\u0067', 
            '\u0068', '\u0069', '\u006A', '\u006B', '\u006C', '\u006D', '\u006E', '\u006F', 
            '\u0070', '\u0071', '\u0072', '\u0073', '\u0074', '\u0075', '\u0076', '\u0077', 
            '\u0078', '\u0079', '\u007A', '\u007B', '\u007C', '\u007D', '\u007E', '\u007F', 
            '\u0080', '\u0081', '\u0082', '\u0083', '\u0084', '\u0085', '\u0086', '\u0087', 
            '\u0088', '\u0089', '\u008A', '\u008B', '\u008C', '\u008D', '\u008E', '\u008F', 
            '\u0090', '\u0091', '\u0092', '\u0093', '\u0094', '\u0095', '\u0096', '\u0097', 
            '\u0098', '\u0099', '\u009A', '\u009B', '\u009C', '\u009D', '\u009E', '\u009F', 
            '\u00A0', '\u058E', '\u0587', '\u0589', '\u0029', '\u0028', '\u00BB', '\u00AB', 
            '\u2015', '\u00B7', '\u055D', '\u002C', '\u2010', '\u058A', '\u2026', '\u055C', 
            '\u055B', '\u055E', '\u0531', '\u0561', '\u0532', '\u0562', '\u0533', '\u0563', 
            '\u0534', '\u0564', '\u0535', '\u0565', '\u0536', '\u0566', '\u0537', '\u0567', 
            '\u0538', '\u0568', '\u0539', '\u0569', '\u053A', '\u056A', '\u053B', '\u056B', 
            '\u053C', '\u056C', '\u053D', '\u056D', '\u053E', '\u056E', '\u053F', '\u056F', 
            '\u0540', '\u0570', '\u0541', '\u0571', '\u0542', '\u0572', '\u0543', '\u0573', 
            '\u0544', '\u0574', '\u0545', '\u0575', '\u0546', '\u0576', '\u0547', '\u0577', 
            '\u0548', '\u0578', '\u0549', '\u0579', '\u054A', '\u057A', '\u054B', '\u057B', 
            '\u054C', '\u057C', '\u054D', '\u057D', '\u054E', '\u057E', '\u054F', '\u057F', 
            '\u0550', '\u0580', '\u0551', '\u0581', '\u0552', '\u0582', '\u0553', '\u0583', 
            '\u0554', '\u0584', '\u0555', '\u0585', '\u0556', '\u0586', '\u055A', '\0'/**/, 
        });

        private ArmSCII8Decoder decoder;
        private ArmSCII8Encoder encoder;

        /// <summary>
        /// This should be thread safe. The worst case is that two instances
        /// of ArmSCII8Decoder are created at the same time, but this isn't
        /// a problem, because ArmSCII8Decoder as used in this class is 
        /// stateless.
        /// </summary>
        protected ArmSCII8Decoder Decoder
        {
            get
            {
                ArmSCII8Decoder decoder2 = decoder;

                // Lazy creation of Encoder
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(decoder2, null))
                {
                    decoder2 = decoder = new ArmSCII8Decoder();
                }

                DecoderFallback decoderFallback = DecoderFallback;

                // If the Fallback has changed from the last call, update it
                if (!object.ReferenceEquals(decoderFallback, null) && !object.ReferenceEquals(decoderFallback, decoder2.Fallback))
                {
                    decoder2.Fallback = decoderFallback;
                }

                return decoder2;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This should be thread safe. The worst case is that two instances
        /// of ArmSCII8Encoder are created at the same time, but this isn't
        /// a problem, because ArmSCII8Encoder as used in this class is 
        /// stateless.
        /// </summary>
        protected ArmSCII8Encoder Encoder
        {
            get
            {
                ArmSCII8Encoder encoder2 = encoder;

                // Lazy creation of Encoder
                if (object.ReferenceEquals(encoder2, null))
                {
                    encoder = encoder2 = new ArmSCII8Encoder();
                }

                EncoderFallback encoderFallback = EncoderFallback;

                // If the Fallback has changed from the last call, update it
                if (!object.ReferenceEquals(encoderFallback, null) && !object.ReferenceEquals(encoderFallback, encoder2.Fallback))
                {
                    encoder2.Fallback = encoderFallback;
                }

                return encoder2;
            }
        }

        public override string BodyName
        {
            get
            {
                return "x-armscii-8-simple";
            }
        }

        public override string EncodingName
        {
            get
            {
                return BodyName;
            }
        }

        public override bool IsSingleByte
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public override object Clone()
        {
            var encoding = (ArmSCII8EncodingSimple)base.Clone();

            // We reset the encoder and decoder of the cloned instance,
            // because otherwise they would be shared between the two
            // instances.
            encoding.decoder = null;
            encoding.encoder = null;

            return encoding;
        }

        public override Decoder GetDecoder()
        {
            return new ArmSCII8Decoder();
        }

        public override Encoder GetEncoder()
        {
            return new ArmSCII8Encoder();
        }

        public override int GetByteCount(char[] chars, int index, int count)
        {
            return Encoder.GetByteCount(chars, index, count, true);
        }

        public override int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex)
        {
            return Encoder.GetBytes(chars, charIndex, charCount, bytes, byteIndex, true);
        }

        public override int GetCharCount(byte[] bytes, int index, int count)
        {
            return Decoder.GetCharCount(bytes, index, count, true);
        }

        public override int GetChars(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex)
        {
            return Decoder.GetChars(bytes, byteIndex, byteCount, chars, charIndex, true);
        }

        public override int GetMaxByteCount(int charCount)
        {
            return charCount;
        }

        public override int GetMaxCharCount(int byteCount)
        {
            return byteCount;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fully thread safe/reentrant.
    /// </summary>
    public class ArmSCII8Decoder : Decoder
    {
        private static readonly char[] Unicodes = ArmSCII8EncodingSimple.Unicodes.ToArray();

        public override int GetCharCount(byte[] bytes, int index, int count)
        {
            if (bytes == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");
            }

            if (index < 0 || index > bytes.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            }

            if (count < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
            }

            if (index + count > bytes.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bytes");
            }

            // The fallbackBuffer is created on-demand. The instance 
            // FallbackBuffer isn't used because it wouldn't be thread safe.
            DecoderFallbackBuffer fallbackBuffer = null;

            int ret = 0;

            int count2 = index + count;

            for (; index < count2; index++)
            {
                byte b = bytes[index];

                char ch = Unicodes[b];

                if (ch != '\0' || b == 0)
                {
                    ret++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (fallbackBuffer == null)
                    {
                        fallbackBuffer = (Fallback ?? DecoderFallback.ReplacementFallback).CreateFallbackBuffer();
                    }

                    // Fallback
                    if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(new[] { b }, index))
                    {
                        HandleFallbackCount(fallbackBuffer, ref ret);
                    }
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

        public override int GetChars(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, int byteCount, char[] chars, int charIndex)
        {
            if (bytes == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");
            }

            if (byteIndex < 0 || byteIndex > bytes.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteIndex");
            }

            if (byteCount < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteCount");
            }

            if (byteIndex + byteCount > bytes.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("bytes");
            }

            if (chars == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("chars");
            }

            if (charIndex < 0 || charIndex > chars.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charIndex");
            }

            // The fallbackBuffer is created on-demand. The instance 
            // FallbackBuffer isn't used because it wouldn't be thread safe.
            DecoderFallbackBuffer fallbackBuffer = null;

            int byteCount2 = byteCount + byteIndex;
            int charIndex2 = charIndex;

            for (; byteIndex < byteCount2; byteIndex++)
            {
                byte b = bytes[byteIndex];

                // chars between 0 and 127 are equal in Unicode and ArmSCII8
                if (b >= 0 && b <= 127)
                {
                    WriteChar(chars, charIndex2, (char)b);
                    charIndex2++;
                }
                else
                {
                    char ch = Unicodes[b];

                    if (ch != '\0' || b == 0)
                    {
                        WriteChar(chars, charIndex2, ch);
                        charIndex2++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fallbackBuffer == null)
                        {
                            fallbackBuffer = (Fallback ?? DecoderFallback.ReplacementFallback).CreateFallbackBuffer();
                        }

                        // Fallback
                        if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(new[] { b }, byteIndex))
                        {
                            HandleFallbackWrite(fallbackBuffer, chars, ref charIndex2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return charIndex2 - charIndex;
        }

        protected static void HandleFallbackCount(DecoderFallbackBuffer fallbackBuffer, ref int count)
        {
            while (fallbackBuffer.Remaining > 0)
            {
                fallbackBuffer.GetNextChar();
                count++;
            }
        }

        protected static void HandleFallbackWrite(DecoderFallbackBuffer fallbackBuffer, char[] chars, ref int charIndex)
        {
            while (fallbackBuffer.Remaining > 0)
            {
                char ch = fallbackBuffer.GetNextChar();

                WriteChar(chars, charIndex, ch);
                charIndex++;
            }
        }

        // Remove the next line if using .NET < 4.5
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        protected static void WriteChar(char[] chars, int charIndex, char ch)
        {
            if (charIndex >= chars.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("bytes");
            }

            chars[charIndex] = ch;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// An instance is thread safe/fully reentrant if the methods are always
    /// called with flush = true.
    /// </summary>
    public class ArmSCII8Encoder : Encoder
    {
        private static readonly byte[] ArmSCII8s;

        // Buffer for High/Low surrogates. Note that this property is read
        // but not written if the methods are always used with flush = true.
        protected char HighSurrogate { get; set; }

        static ArmSCII8Encoder()
        {
            ArmSCII8s = new byte[1 + ArmSCII8EncodingSimple.Unicodes.Max()];

            for (int i = 0; i < ArmSCII8EncodingSimple.Unicodes.Count; i++)
            {
                char ch = ArmSCII8EncodingSimple.Unicodes[i];

                if (i == 0 || (ArmSCII8s[ch] == 0 && ch != '\0'))
                {
                    ArmSCII8s[ch] = (byte)i;
                }
            }
        }

        public override int GetByteCount(char[] chars, int index, int count, bool flush)
        {
            if (chars == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("chars");
            }

            if (index < 0 || index > chars.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");
            }

            if (count < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("count");
            }

            if (index + count > chars.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chars");
            }

            // The fallbackBuffer is created on-demand. The instance 
            // FallbackBuffer isn't used because it wouldn't be thread safe.
            EncoderFallbackBuffer fallbackBuffer = null;

            char highSurrogate = HighSurrogate;

            int ret = 0;

            int count2 = index + count;

            for (; index < count2; index++)
            {
                char ch = chars[index];

                if (highSurrogate != 0)
                {
                    if (fallbackBuffer == null)
                    {
                        fallbackBuffer = (Fallback ?? EncoderFallback.ReplacementFallback).CreateFallbackBuffer();
                    }

                    // If we have a High/Low surrogates couple, we pass them 
                    // together
                    if (char.IsLowSurrogate(ch))
                    {
                        if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(highSurrogate, ch, index - 1))
                        {
                            HandleFallbackCount(fallbackBuffer, ref ret);
                        }

                        highSurrogate = '\0';

                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // First we pass the High surrogate to the Fallback
                        if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(highSurrogate, index - 1))
                        {
                            HandleFallbackCount(fallbackBuffer, ref ret);
                        }

                        highSurrogate = '\0';

                        // Then we fall-through normal handling
                    }
                }

                if (ch < ArmSCII8s.Length && (ArmSCII8s[ch] != 0 || ch == '\0'))
                {
                    ret++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // High/low surrogate handling, done through buffer
                    if (char.IsHighSurrogate(ch))
                    {
                        highSurrogate = ch;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fallbackBuffer == null)
                        {
                            fallbackBuffer = (Fallback ?? EncoderFallback.ReplacementFallback).CreateFallbackBuffer();
                        }

                        // Fallback
                        if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(ch, index))
                        {
                            HandleFallbackCount(fallbackBuffer, ref ret);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (flush)
            {
                if (highSurrogate != 0)
                {
                    if (fallbackBuffer == null)
                    {
                        fallbackBuffer = (Fallback ?? EncoderFallback.ReplacementFallback).CreateFallbackBuffer();
                    }

                    if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(highSurrogate, index - 1))
                    {
                        HandleFallbackCount(fallbackBuffer, ref ret);
                    }
                }
            }

            return ret;
        }

        public override int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, bool flush)
        {
            if (chars == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("chars");
            }

            if (charIndex < 0 || charIndex > chars.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charIndex");
            }

            if (charCount < 0)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charCount");
            }

            if (charIndex + charCount > chars.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("chars");
            }

            if (bytes == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");
            }

            if (byteIndex < 0 || byteIndex > bytes.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteIndex");
            }

            // The fallbackBuffer is created on-demand. The instance 
            // FallbackBuffer isn't used because it wouldn't be thread safe.
            EncoderFallbackBuffer fallbackBuffer = null;

            // Written only on flush = false
            char highSurrogate = HighSurrogate;

            int charCount2 = charIndex + charCount;
            int byteIndex2 = byteIndex;

            for (; charIndex < charCount2; charIndex++)
            {
                char ch = chars[charIndex];

                if (highSurrogate != 0)
                {
                    if (fallbackBuffer == null)
                    {
                        fallbackBuffer = (Fallback ?? EncoderFallback.ReplacementFallback).CreateFallbackBuffer();
                    }

                    // If we have a High/Low surrogates couple, we pass them 
                    // together
                    if (char.IsLowSurrogate(ch))
                    {
                        if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(highSurrogate, ch, charIndex - 1))
                        {
                            HandleFallbackWrite(fallbackBuffer, bytes, ref byteIndex2);
                        }

                        highSurrogate = '\0';

                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // First we pass the High surrogate to the Fallback
                        if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(highSurrogate, charIndex - 1))
                        {
                            HandleFallbackWrite(fallbackBuffer, bytes, ref byteIndex2);
                        }

                        highSurrogate = '\0';

                        // Then we fall-through normal handling
                    }
                }

                byte b;

                if (ch < ArmSCII8s.Length && ((b = ArmSCII8s[ch]) != 0 || ch == '\0'))
                {
                    // Recognized character
                    WriteByte(bytes, byteIndex2, b);
                    byteIndex2++;
                }
                else
                {
                    // High/low surrogate handling, done through buffer
                    if (char.IsHighSurrogate(ch))
                    {
                        highSurrogate = ch;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (fallbackBuffer == null)
                        {
                            fallbackBuffer = (Fallback ?? EncoderFallback.ReplacementFallback).CreateFallbackBuffer();
                        }

                        // Fallback
                        if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(ch, charIndex))
                        {
                            HandleFallbackWrite(fallbackBuffer, bytes, ref byteIndex2);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (flush)
            {
                if (highSurrogate != 0)
                {
                    if (fallbackBuffer == null)
                    {
                        fallbackBuffer = (Fallback ?? EncoderFallback.ReplacementFallback).CreateFallbackBuffer();
                    }

                    if (fallbackBuffer.Fallback(highSurrogate, charIndex - 1))
                    {
                        HandleFallbackWrite(fallbackBuffer, bytes, ref byteIndex2);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                HighSurrogate = highSurrogate;
            }

            return byteIndex2 - byteIndex;
        }

        protected static void HandleFallbackCount(EncoderFallbackBuffer fallbackBuffer, ref int count)
        {
            while (fallbackBuffer.Remaining > 0)
            {
                char ch = fallbackBuffer.GetNextChar();

                if (!(ch < ArmSCII8s.Length && (ArmSCII8s[ch] != 0 || ch == '\0')))
                {
                    throw new EncoderFallbackException();
                }

                count++;
            }
        }

        protected static void HandleFallbackWrite(EncoderFallbackBuffer fallbackBuffer, byte[] bytes, ref int byteIndex)
        {
            while (fallbackBuffer.Remaining > 0)
            {
                char ch = fallbackBuffer.GetNextChar();

                byte b;

                if (!(ch < ArmSCII8s.Length && ((b = ArmSCII8s[ch]) != 0 || ch == '\0')))
                {
                    throw new EncoderFallbackException();
                }

                WriteByte(bytes, byteIndex, b);
                byteIndex++;
            }
        }

        // Remove the next line if using .NET < 4.5
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
        protected static void WriteByte(byte[] bytes, int byteIndex, byte b)
        {
            if (byteIndex == bytes.Length)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("bytes");
            }

            bytes[byteIndex] = b;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
public static string DecodeFromArmSCII8(string str) {
    // copy the string as UTF-8 bytes.
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(str);
    return new ArmSCII8EncodingSimple().GetString(bytes);
}
```

and

```
string str = DecodeFromArmSCII8("Ø³ñïÇñáëÛ³Ý ²ÉÇÝ³ Ø.");
```

The `Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1").GetBytes(str)` returns the original `byte[]` array. Note that if you have the original `byte[]` you can directly use the `ArmSCII8EncodingFast`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH
it works, only char և cannot convert for that i use Replace()
thanks

Comment: Do you have a collection for Russian fonts?

Comment: @HaykMelqonyan No, I build the code when someone asks it in a question. I have some base code I had used for a similar question for vietnamese and then readapt the code (see the big table in the beginning of the code? You only have to change it). I look around the internet (the wiki for example) for the encoding table.

Comment: Where i can find that table for russian characters?

Comment: @HaykMelqonyan Some of them are already inside .NET: `Encoding.GetEncoding([one of 855, 866, 20866, 28595])`. Begin with the 28595, that is the ISO 8859-5 Cyrillic. There is even the 28594 (baltic) and  the 28603 (estonian)